# JavaEE out.println cannot resolve method

Tags: java-ee, maven, servlet, tomcat

Начал изучение JavaEE.
Проект построен в IntelliJ IDEA на Maven, TomCat 9.

Идешка отмечает, что не находит метода println у out. После того, как запаковал - код отрабатывает. Но не знаю насколько правильно - не переносит строку, т.е. судя по синтаксису должно выводить каждую запись(цифру) на новой строке - но выводит через пробел.

Как сделать так, чтобы Иде знала о методах у out и чтобы все отрабатывало верно?

pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
<version>0.1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.53</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Hello JSP</title>
   </head>
<body>
  <h1.>Testing JSP</h1>
<p>
  <%
    Date now = new Date();
    String dateNow = "Time is: " + now;
  %>
  <%= "Hello World!" %>
  <%= dateNow %>


</p>
<p>
  <%
    for (int i =0; i < 10; i++) {
      out.println(i);
    }
  %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за многочисленные ответы и минусы. После перерыва в поисках, пришла идея полазить в библиотеках установленного tomcat и нашел то, что нужно.
Для того, чтобы ИДЕшка не жаловалась на метод, необходимо подключить зависимость:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.31</version>
    </dependency>
```

Странно, что у out есть методы print и println, но println не выводит на новой строке. Нашел рекомендацию оборачивать каждый вывод в параграф:

```
  <%
    for (int i =0; i < 10; i++) {
      out.println("<p>" + i + "</p>");
    }
  %>
```

Comment: Вам println и не должен выводить на новой строке. Вы путаете вывод в консоль, и вывод в jsp. Прочтите, придет понимание почему с тэгом вывод работает -  http://htmlbook.ru/html/p